# App as an SMS/MMs attachment

Tags: android, ios, mobile, cordova

I am right now trying to design a mobile app as a personal project. Initially I thought about doing in java as a native android application. Now I am thinking about doing it in phonegap so it could run on every platform (If you have a recommendation of a diffrent framework I would be happy to hear).

Now to my question:
When you send an sms on your phone it is possible to click on the attach button to open up a dialog where you can select an app to attach its contents. For example, choose camera to take a phote and send it out immediately.

I want to also register my app as an sms attachment service but I am unsure how to do this. I am sure I can do it in Java somehow but what if I use phonegap? I am sure phonegap will restrict me in some ways.

Another followup questions:
Is it possible to get the same effect with WhatsApp (a popular web text service, big in Europe but not so much in the US)?

Comment: forget about cordova/phonegap because in any case to provide the functionality you want most of the time you have to write native code.

Comment: This is very sad to hear. When I researched online those frameworks seem promising... What about appcelerator? Also no good?